# Passing arguments to a function inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function `addFrom` which is triggered by a button. I would like to reuse changing the target ID and class. It works when I don't add any arguments. This is done using `$(document).ready(function()` as shown below, but when I try to use an argument it works only the first time
I don't understand how can I use the function passing some arguments using `$(document).ready`.

```js
function addForm(TF) {
  var $templateForm = $(TF);
  console.log($templateForm)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(addForm('#form2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a id="add" href="#">Add form</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap in a function

I would also use .on and prevent the default action

```js
function addForm(TF) {
  const $templateForm = $(TF);
  console.log($templateForm)
}


$(document).ready(function() { // shorter: $(function() {
  $('#add').on('click',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    addForm('#form2');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="add" href="#">Add form</a>

<form id="form2"></form>
```

jQuery can help you though passing data, but I find it harder to read

```js
function addForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const $templateForm = $(event.data.TF);
  console.log($templateForm)
}


$(function() {
  $('#add').on('click',{'TF':'#form2'},addForm)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="add" href="#">Add form</a>

<form id="form2"></form>
```

Comment: `$(function() {` is the exact same as `$(document).ready(function() {` just shorter - see update

Comment: Also `$('#add').on('click',function(e) {`  is a more versatile version of `$('#add').click(function(e) { `

Comment: BTW, If you do `$("something").someEvent(somefunction())` where you have () on somefunction, the somefunction is executed immediately the browser sees the code

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(){
    addForm('#form2');
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope It's Help You